# I'm trying to make a page navigation bar using express framework and pug library when I hit my endpoint demo page I got nothing on my screen. please h

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

```
enter code here
```

//Here is my app.js code, I want to make a basic routing navigation bar, here demo is my file name. I want to insert some HTML into the demo page but got nothing on the browser screen

````
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = 80;

// For serving static files
app.use("/static", express.static("static"));

// Set the template engine as pug
app.set("view engine", "pug");

// Set the views directory
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

// Our pug demo endpoint
app.get("/demo", (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .render("demo", {
      title: "Hey Harry",
      message: "Hello there and thanks for telling me how to use pubG!",
    });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("This is homepage of my first express app with Harry");
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.send("This is about page of my first express app with Harry");
});

app.post("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.send(
    "This is a post request about page of my first express app with Harry"
  );
});
app.get("/this", (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send("This page is not found on my website cwh");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The application started successfully on port ${port}`);
});```

    

    
    enter code here
//& Here is my code for demo.pug

  ```html 
      head 
        title=title 
      body 
        h1 = message```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. Please remove the backticks at the end of your file,
2. Please include this line in your file: `const express = require("express");`
3. You can use EJS instead of pug. It is more popular and easier to write and understand.
4. Assuming you have `views` folder at the root, you can delete this line:

```
// Set the views directory
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```

5. Adding one more `res` will make your code look more stylish and also less buggy (For instance, message line shouldn't have comma at the end):

```
app.get("/demo", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200);
  res.render("demo", {
      title: "Hey Harry",
      message: "Hello there and thanks for telling me how to use pubG!"
  });
});
```

I checked the your code on my computer and it worked. Please try the steps above and let me know if it works.

Comment: Sir, it still not work the problem remain same

Comment: Can you please share the error text?

Comment: thank you sir Now its work, actually after restarting the node server it worked fine, actually, it's my a silly mistake, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked.